# Hierarchal Bayes: logistic regression

Tags: logistic, hierarchical-bayesian, pymc, logistic-curve

We have the following model that was proposed to me. It takes yes, no and maybe responses to try and predict attendance $y_{i}$.

$$
\begin{align}
y_i &\sim \mathsf{Bin}(n, p_i) \\
p_i &= \mathrm{logit}^{-1}\big(\beta_0 + \beta_1 I_{X=1} + \beta_2 I_{X\in (0,1)} x_i\big)
\end{align}
$$

dummy variables: $I_{X=1}$ that returns 1 if $X=1$ and 0 otherwise, and $I_{X∈(0,1)}$ that returns 1 if X is in the (0,1) range (i.e. excluding the exact 0 and 1) and 0 otherwise

Such that :
$$
\mathrm{logit}(p_i) = 
\begin{cases}
\beta_0  & X = 0 \\ 
\beta_0 + \beta_1 & X = 1 \\ 
\beta_0 + \beta_2 x_i & X \in (0, 1) 
\end{cases}
$$
This was explained to me by a user named Tim and seems a lot better than my original idea.

So I am able to get $p_{i}$ but I don't quite think I actually understand what I am getting. It's obviously a logistic function as $p_{i}$ vs $z(x)$ where $z(x) = \mathrm{logit}^{-1}\big(\beta_0 + \beta_1 I_{X=1} + \beta_2 I_{X\in (0,1)} x_i\big)$. My problem is in interpreting the graph in terms of probability of attending or not attending and how I should fit it to the given binomial distribution. I get the following. Note the $z$ values.

[image]

The above graph is much different to something like this which would sum up to one. I would interpret values where $z>0$ as probability to attend and $z<0$ as not attending probability.

[image]

Should I perhaps rescale the $z$ values by dividing by $n$ to get a domain of $[-1,1]$

Really not sure here to be honest. Would you please explain this to me please. Thank you.

Link to original question: [Bayesian Modeling: Yes, No and Maybe Responses](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319890/bayesian-modeling-yes-no-and-maybe-responses)

Comment: How is Hierarchical Bayes related to your question? What Tim suggested looks self-sufficient in a frequentist framework.

Comment: I'm really to be honest out of my depth here and trying to get a foot into the Bayesian framework of things. I guess it's because of the informative priors perhaps suggested by the $/beta_{i} $ distributions. I'm sort of just trying to understand how to interpret the logistic plot. I can't intuitively explain it.

Comment: What you're seeing is simply a plot of the logistic function that you would similarly get with the plain R code: _x=-10:10; plot(x, 1/(1+exp(-x)))_. Still, I don't think trying to learn Bayesian estimation combined with logistic regression is a good idea.