# Why no variance term in Bayesian logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, bayesian, generalized-linear-model, variance, bernoulli-distribution

I've read [here](http://www.medicine.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/joseph/courses/EPIB-621/bayeslogit.pdf) that

> ... (Bayesian linear regression) is most similar to Bayesian inference
>   in logistic regression, but in some ways logistic regression is even
>   simpler, because there is no variance term to estimate, only the
>   regression parameters.

Why is it the case, why no variance term in Bayesian logistic regression?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163034/bayesian-logit-model-intuitive-explanation/163039#163039), Bayesian or not, is a model defined in terms of [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution). The distribution is parametrized by "probability of success" $p$ with mean $p$ and variance $p(1-p)$, i.e. the variance directly follows from the mean. So there is no "separate" variance term, this is what the quote seems to say.

Comment: @patrick for linear regression $y = mx + c + \epsilon$, whereas logistic regression p(y=1|x) = logistic(mx +c).

Comment: @seanv507 and would it make sense to have $p(y=1|x)=logistic(mx+c+\epsilon)$ or not? If not, is it because $p()$ is a probability and already includes some uncertainty?

Comment: @Patrick what would this formulation exactly mean? Could you give an example where would you imagine it to be used?

Comment: @Patrick When you describe the conditional expectation in terms of a distribution there's no error term.

Comment: Not really, I was just comparing the linear and the logistic descriptions, first has $\epsilon$, the second one has not. I foolishly believed that we can have an error term in both. @Firebug By distribution you mean the logistic right (which is a cumulative distribution)?

Comment: @Patrick linear regression is $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(X\beta, \sigma)$ while logistic regression is $Y \sim \mathcal{B}(h^{-1}(X\beta))$. Error term is alternative way of writing linear regression, but in both cases you estimate mean of some distribution. So error term *inside* logistic regression would mean that you assume $h(p)$ to be normally distributed. This does not have to be nonsense, but I doubt that this is what you meant.

Comment: You're right. Thank you again, it's very clear! Don't you think the author meant that there is no error term inside logistic regression (in general)?